# Regex to match certain function and all it's contents

Tags: java, regex

I have a c file having several functions, and I need to extract a particular function and it's whole content as below. It's name is Start and it ends with comment /* Start */

```
FUNC(boolean, CODE) Start(Type Mode) {
  boolean disp;
  // more code
  // more code
  // more code
  } /* Start */
```

I wrote following regex:

```
(FUNC\(boolean, CODE\) Start\(Type Mode\) \{)(.*)(\} \/\* Start \*\/)
```

but it's not matching next line with .*

I need to write this utility in Java.

Here's the link for regex: https://regex101.com/r/yT5EqX/1/

Comment: You can make the dot match a newline using the `s` flag. See https://regex101.com/r/PF022d/1 Note that `.*` will match till the end of all lines, and will then backtrack until the last occurrence. You could make it non greedy `.*?`

Comment: Or just replace `(.*)` with `([\s\S]*?)`, which will non-greedily match 0 or more characters that are whitespace or non-whitespace (in other words, *any* character).